# Polylang for WooCommerce - next emails translation issue

Tags: email, woocommerce, translation, polylang

Thats my first time with Polylang plugin for Woo. Ive translated everything which is necessary Ig we are talking about e-mails, for sure. Our shop is designed to buy without creating account so if customer picked up English language and order something he received order confirmation in right language, but any next emails (which are genereted automatically) like invoice or order it is not in English, only headers are translated. There we missed something?

I am sure that all strings are translated. We also have plugin installed like „WPML for Polylang” but I am not sure it is related.

Please advice what should I check.

- checked all string which are used in e-mail templates

Comment: This is a vague explanation. Are the products translated? Is your theme overwriting woo emails? we can guess only what you use and how you set up your plugin. Do you have Polylang woo version or just Polylang? these are different things. I would recommend contacting polylang support to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.